# Python: install package is failed

Tags: python, pip

I have installed Python 3.6 and pip 9.0.1. I'd like to install SimpleITK package but it doesn't find a version that satisfies the requirements SimpleITK (img 1). I tried to install it with .whl files but it isn't supported. I can't understand what the problem is and how to decide it. [image: img1][image]

Comment: You might have to downgrade. Downgrade to py3.4 or 2.7

Comment: It means it doesn't exist for python 3.6 yet.

Comment: @kawadhiya21 thank you, that worked